# Wand load only first page from blob

Tags: wand

I'm loading my images from a blob and I would like to load only the first page. I know this is possible with the [0] syntax when it is in a file but is there a way to do that without writing my image to the disk? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```py
with Image(blob=my_image_blob, format="PDF[0]") as img:
    pass
```

Where `"PDF[0]"` is replaced with the correct decoder. Like `"PS[0]"`, `"GIF[0]"`. or `'TIFF[0]"` as examples.